# FreeMarker - Handeling Json which includes int

Tags: java, json, loops, freemarker

I'm attempting to create a script which will check id and export the name of it but I'm encountering the following;

---

FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):

### - Failed at: #assign services = {"externalId": 1  [in nameless template at line 1, column 1]

```
<#list [services] as st><#if st.externalId == externalId>${st.name}</#if>
<#list st.children as nd<#if nd.externalId == externalId>${nd.name}</#if>
<#list nd.children as rd><#if rd.externalId == externalId>${rd.name}</#if>
<#list rd.children as th><#if th.externalId == externalId>${th.name}</#if>
<#list th.children as ths><#if ths.externalId == externalId>${ths.name}</#if>
<#list ths.children as thb><#if thb.externalId == externalId>${thb.name}</#if>
</#list></#list></#list></#list></#list></#list>`
```

the script works fine if all the externalID had numbers but they can also be null when it's null I get an error;

```
<#assign services=
{
"externalId": 1,
"name": "one",
"children": [
    {
        "externalId": 2,
        "name": "two",
        "children": [ 
            {
                "externalId": null,
                "name": "three",
                "children": [
                   {
                             "externalId": 4,
                             "name": "four",
                             "children": [
                                {
                                         "externalId": 5,
                                         "name": "five",
                                         "children": []
                                }         ]
                    }       ]
            }]
     }]
}>
```

I've been testing on https://try.freemarker.apache.org/

Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

In FreeMarker you (almost) always have to specify a default where you expect `null`-s to appear. Like: `nd.externalId! == external` will consider `nd.externalId` as an empty string in case it's `null`. Or, `${th.name!'null'}` will print `null` when `th.name` is `null`.